# Find an algorithm with O(n) for making Chairlifts on N mountains

Tags: algorithms

Today, I encountered an interesting problem in my textbook. The problem is:
Utopia city has N mountains with height of $$h_{1}, h_{2}, h_{3}, ..., h_{n}$$. We want to make a chairlifts which pass from the top of k consecutive mountain. To do this, we have to make the height of **all** these mountains the same. If the secondary height of mountains are $$d_{1}, d_{2}, d_{3}, ..., d_{n}$$, the cost of building chairlifts from mountain #t to 
the mountain #t+k-1 is:

$$\sum_{i=t}^{t + k -1} (h_{i} - d_{i})$$

We are looking for an algorithm to find the minimum cost of building the chairlifts in $$O(n).$$

in the book it is mentioned that it is easy to find the algorithm. But it doesn't mention the algorithm. I can't think of an O(n) algorithm as a solution.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Can we make a mountain higher than it is?

Comment: @ftfish No, we can just decrease the height of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let $PS[i]$ be the prefix sum of $h$ (sum of $h_1,\ldots,h_i$). So we can calculate the sum of any interval in $O(1)$.
2. Do some preprocessing on $h$ in $O(n)$ time, so that we can answer Range Minimum Queries (RMQs) in $O(1)$. See [Wiki page for RMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_Minimum_Query).
3. Run through all possible starting positions, calculate the sum of the next $k$ mountains, and get the minimum height of those mountains, and calculate the cost of building the chairlift there (that is, $sum - minimum \times k$). Record the minimum cost.

---

**Update:**

It is important to note all ranges we run RMQ on are of length $k$. It is therefore possible to exploit this fact and find simpler algorithm to answer those RMQs. I'll try to explain such an algorithm in the following.

Consider the equivalent problem of finding the minimum of all length $k$ sub-arrays for every *ending* position $i$.

We maintain a *monotone queue* (actually deque) $Q$ of our active set, that is,  only those elements that could still be the minimum of the current interval are stored in $Q$.

Consider e.g. $Q=[h_1=1,h_3=7,h_7=9,h_9=13]$, $i=10$ and $h_i=8$.

From this point on, we are sure that $h_9$ and $h_7$ can never be the minimum for any ending positions after $i$ (inclusively) because $h_i=8$ comes after them, they are in a sense "dominated" by $h_i$. Therefore we drop those elements at the end of the queue which are larger than or equal to $h_i$, and then append $h_i$ to the queue, resulting in a new monotone queue $Q'=[h_1=1,h_3=7,h_{10}=8]$.

Then, we remove all elements that are too far away from $i$, from the beginning of $Q'$. E.g. if $k=8$, then $h_1$ is too far away from $h_{10}$, resulting in $Q''=[h_3=7,h_{10}=8]$.

From this queue, we choose the first element. That will be the minimum of the length-$k$ sub-array ending at $i$.

The algorithm is $O(n)$, because every element can only be in the queue at most once, and be dropped at most once. The total cost is therefore $O(n)$, although it could also take up to $O(n)$ in a single position $i$.

Comment: Can you please explain more about "some preprocessing" which you mentioned?

Comment: @PardisPashakhanloo See e.g. this paper. http://pdf.aminer.org/000/118/469/theoretical_and_practical_improvements_on_the_rmq_problem_with_applications.pdf Actually, Google reveals many resources on this. However if you haven't heard of RMQ before, then this algorithm might not be what your book is referring to.

Comment: @PardisPashakhanloo A new algorithm to answer RMQs is added. Hope I've made it clear.

Comment: @PardisPashakhanloo glad it helped! You could consider accepting this answer :)